# PostgreSQL 8.0 to Microsoft SQL Server 2008 migration

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I am migrating a large (500 GB) database containing several hundred tables and a few database functions from PostgreSQL 8.0 to Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Is there a website (or book) that details differences I need to be aware of (data types, stored procedure functionality, etc.)?

I am fairly familiar with PostgreSQL, but just learning SQL Server.

Any SQL Server book recommendations would also be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Try Postgresql 9. However, if you really need to migrate to SQL Server 2008, try to use SSIS, it's a superb utility

Comment: Btw, I'm curious why the need to migrate your Postgres database to Sql Server?

Comment: @Hao: Enterprise decision. Enough said.

Comment: I thought it's technical decision. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at these links:

[Microsoft SQL Server to PostgreSQL Migration by Ian Harding](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server_to_PostgreSQL_Migration_by_Ian_Harding)

This is going the other way, but has some of the information you need.

[Cross compare of SQL SERVER 2005, MYSQL, and PostgreSQL 8.3](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/51-Cross-Compare-of-SQL-Server,-MySQL,-and-PostgreSQL.html)